# why my Listbox data binding using DataContext is not working?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, datacontext

I am new to WPF and data binding,
here I have a Listbox which works just fine:

```
    <ListBox 
        x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllFriends}">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now I want to try DataContext so I use:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
      x:Key="FriendsGroups" 
      Source="{Binding Path=AllFriends}"
      >
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

   <ListBox 
        x:Name="listBox" 
        DataContext="{StaticResource FriendsGroups}">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

But this one is not working.
I would appreciate if you could tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you use a `CollectionViewSource`, you still have to set the `ItemsSource` property, not the `DataContext`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FriendsGroups}}">
```